# How can I reconstruct my array without looping?

Tags: php, arrays

I want to transform this array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [group] => site
        [key] => date_format
        [value] => %d %B %Y - %H:%M:%S
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [group] => site
        [key] => description
        [value] => blah
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [group] => site
        [key] => keywords
        [value] => 
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [group] => pages
        [key] => permalink
        [value] => <page>(/<subpage>)
    )

    [4] => Array
    (
        [group] => system
        [key] => plugins
        [value] => a:1:{i:0;s:5:"pages";}
    )

    [5] => Array
    (
        [group] => site
        [key] => title
        [value] => some title
     )
)
```

... to this ...

```
Array
(
    [system] => Array
    (
        [plugins] => a:1:{i:0;s:5:"pages";}
    )

    [site] => Array
    (
        [date_format] => %d %B %Y - %H:%M:%S
        [description] => blah
        [keywords] => 
        [title] => some title
    )

    [pages] => Array
    (
        [permalink] => <page>(/<subpage>)
    )
)
```

Is there any ways to do this without foreach and any other loop?

Comment: Why would you want to do it without loops?

Comment: It's trivial to do with foreach(). Why can't you use it?

Comment: this looks like an database dump, how about using an advanced query

Comment: Do you build that original source array yourself? If so, then you could just build it directly as that second structure. But given that source array as your question asks... of course you have to loop over it. You don't have to use a `foreach` loop, but it would be the most straightforward way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you cannot.

And this micro-optimization would be pointless. Just write a simple foreach loop and stop trying to invent a square wheel.